# Increasing UIButton's intrinsic size when contained in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I've created an UIButton subclass with a view located outside of the bounds of the button.

It looks as on the screenshot:

[image: button]

As you see, the badge is located outside of the button. It's center is anchored to the button's top right corner.

The problem is that when the button is placed inside a `UIBarButtonItem`, the badge gets clipped.

The view hierarchy inspector shows why:

[image: viewhierarchy]

How can I communicate to the `UIBarButtonItem` that the size of the button is larger, than the button itself? What properties of the `UIButton` do I have to override?

The code I use for a button:

```
import UIKit
import BadgeSwift

@objc public class BadgeButton: UIButton {
    private lazy var badge: BadgeSwift = {
        let b = BadgeSwift()
        b.textColor = .white
        b.insets = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        b.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        return b
    }()

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        addSubview(badge)
        badge.text = "1"
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        clipsToBounds = false
        badge.sizeToFit()
        badge.center = center
        badge.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, y: bounds.origin.y)
    }
}
```

For the Badge view I use the following library: [BadgeSwift Library](https://github.com/evgenyneu/swift-badge/)

Comment: Can u post full code? import BadgeSwift , I will try

Comment: I've updated my question with the link to the library I'm using to draw a badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed by adding a clear border around the badge:**

```
import UIKit
import BadgeSwift

@objc public class BadgeButton: UIButton {
    private lazy var badge: BadgeSwift = {
        let b = BadgeSwift()
        b.textColor = .white
        b.borderWidth = 1
        b.borderColor = .clear
        b.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)
        return b
    }()

    public var badgeText: String? {
        get {
            return badge.text
        }
        set {
            badge.text = newValue
        }
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        addSubview(badge)
        badge.text = "1"
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        clipsToBounds = false
        badge.sizeToFit()
        badge.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, y: bounds.origin.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create layer for your `UIBarButtonItem` and shape it.

Create .swift file and paste this code

```
import UIKit


extension CAShapeLayer {
    func drawRoundedRect(rect: CGRect, andColor color: UIColor, filled: Bool) {
        fillColor = filled ? color.cgColor : UIColor.white.cgColor
        strokeColor = color.cgColor
        path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 7).cgPath
    }
}

private var handle: UInt8 = 0;

extension UIBarButtonItem {
     var badgeLayer: CAShapeLayer? {
        if let b: AnyObject = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &handle) as AnyObject? {
            return b as? CAShapeLayer
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func setBadge(text: String?, withOffsetFromTopRight offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero, andColor color:UIColor = UIColor.red, andFilled filled: Bool = true, andFontSize fontSize: CGFloat = 11)
    {
        badgeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

        if (text == nil || text == "") {
            return
        }

        addBadge(text: text!, withOffset: offset, andColor: color, andFilled: filled)
    }

    func addBadge(text: String, withOffset offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero, andColor color: UIColor = UIColor.red, andFilled filled: Bool = true, andFontSize fontSize: CGFloat = 11)
    {
        guard let view = self.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else { return }

        var font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular) }
        let badgeSize = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])

        // Initialize Badge
        let badge = CAShapeLayer()

        let height = badgeSize.height;
        var width = badgeSize.width + 2 /* padding */

        //make sure we have at least a circle
        if (width < height) {
            width = height
        }

        //x position is offset from right-hand side
        let x = view.frame.width - width + offset.x

        let badgeFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: offset.y), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))

        badge.drawRoundedRect(rect: badgeFrame, andColor: color, filled: filled)
        view.layer.addSublayer(badge)

        // Initialiaze Badge's label
        let label = CATextLayer()
        label.string = text
        label.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center
        label.font = font
        label.fontSize = font.pointSize

        label.frame = badgeFrame
        label.foregroundColor = filled ? UIColor.white.cgColor : color.cgColor
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        label.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        badge.addSublayer(label)

        // Save Badge as UIBarButtonItem property
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &handle, badge, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }

    func removeBadge() {
        badgeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

**Usage From your ViewController**

```
//ADD BADGE
self.yourBarBtn.addBadge(text: String(7))

//REMOVE BADGE
self.pendingBarBtn.removeBadge()
```

Comment: The question is about how to make `UIButton` contained in the `UIBarButtonItem` be larger, not how to create a badge.

Comment: You are creating badge seems. So posted this.